# SWI-Prologのread_term_from_atom/3の改行処理にバグがあるのではないか？

Tags: prolog

SWI-Prologの仕様についての質問です。ver 7.1.17 または ver 6.6.1 で確認したことですが、
基本的に現在のこの処理系はソースプログラム中のアトムに改行を含んでよい。それをインタプリタトップが読み込む際に'\n'コードに変換する。5行以上の改行を許可したい場合は、~/src/pl-incl.h の#define NEWLINES 5 の値を大きな値に変えて、コンパイルし直せばよい。そう理解しています。インタプリタトップに於いてもソースプログラムと同様です。
ところが、以下の例では、

```
?- read_term_from_atom('ab
cd',X,[]).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: ab

ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: cd . 
?-
```

とエラーになってしまいます。これは atom_to_term/3 を使っても同じ現象が生じます。
マクロ処理的な前段を含むか含まないか、処理後のアトムを見ているか、処理前のアトムを
見ているか、によって起こっているようにも思えます。

これら述語はごく当たり前に使用する述語であり、もしこのような仕様だとすれば、
その悪影響は甚大であると考えます。これは、正当な理由のある仕様なのでしょうか。
それともバグの類であると考えて、改善を求めるべきなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

これ、すみません。私の勘違いでした。

削除したいところですが、どこに問題があったかを
示すべきなので残します。

私が指摘した問題は、一旦、改行を含むアトムとして、
成功裡に取れた後の、解析フェーズで起こったものでした。
解析対象のアトムが改行を間に挟んだ、

```
'ab
cd'
```

ではエラーになるのは当然でした。abの後にカンマを付加して

```
?- read_term_from_atom('ab,
cd',X,[]).
X = (ab, cd)
```

ならばエラーにはなりません。

つまり、構文エラーにならないような、項として認識できるような
複数行のアトムを与えて確かめなければいけませんでした。

実は、私がアトム中の改行数が多すぎる時に出る
エラーメッセージと構文解析時に出るエラーメッセージを
全く同じもののように錯覚していました。ところが確認して
みると改行数エラーのメッセージは

```
ERROR: Stream User_input:14:1 Syntax error:String too long
```

のようなものであり、全くの別物でした。
ということで、昨夜に書いた釈明ではこの二つの
メッセージが同一だったので混乱したことになって
いましたが、実際には同じではなく、全て私の勘違いで
あったことがわかりました。

返す返す、お騒がせして、申し訳ありません。